# Using Function from User-Defined Script in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have placed a MATLAB script "x.m" in the path of my current working directory. So the script is in folder "~/a" and my working directory is "~/a/b"
But MATLAB seems to be not recognizing that the single function 'x' in the script exists? I have named the file exactly the same as function, which works properly when I place the script in my exact working directory rather than just on the path of my working directory. I believe my version is MATLAB2016a, if that makes any difference. Before updating to MATLAB2016a, I had made a similar function and was able to use it properly with just putting the script in the path of my working directory.

Suggestions/solutions?

Comment: You can't just have a function in the parent directory and expect MATLAB to find it. There is a thing called the MATLAB path, which is the collection of directories MATLAB will search to find functions. You can add directories to it using `addpath`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo that makes sense, though that's exactly what I have done in the past. (I really don't like MATLAB and ought to just switch back to a full programming language at some point.) Thanks for the comment. I'll accept it as the correct answer if you want to post it as an answer! :)

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much! Now I just have a "matlab_stuffs" folder which is for all my matlab functions. This will work great for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just have a function in the parent directory and expect MATLAB to find it. There is a thing called the [MATLAB path](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html), which is the collection of directories MATLAB will search to find functions. You can add directories to it using [addpath](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html).